# Trying to remove span tags with dynamic style attributes

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow user submitted HTML in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376825/allow-user-submitted-html-in-php)

I'm building a small tool that publishes web articles to our website. A lot of the times our users are copying and pasting directly from Microsoft Word into my wysiwyg editor. The editor copies all of the Word hidden tags.

My main issue I am trying to address is removing `<span>`. Word often throws in a lot of style attributes after the `<span>` tag. For example: `<span style=" Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; ">`.

Is there a way to remove the entire span tag? Regex?

Comment: Parse it with the DOM. Regex doesn't work with HTML, as HTML is not a regular language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're set on using a regex for it you could try something like

```
"/^(<span)+([A-Za-z0-9=,;:])*(>)+$/"
```

Where the `(<span)+(>)+` catches both opening and closing tags and the middle section should catch any attributes declared inline. Then you could use php preg_replace to replace all occurrences of this pattern with empty quotes or something like that.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php