# Disable html in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I wanted to disable HTML in a div simply because I want just a plain text to be shown inside a div.

If you retrieve a data from the DB and it's value is `<b> Good! </b>` which is equivalent to **Good!** in HTML. Now what I want is that, I wanted to show the word `<b> Good! </b>` (without html style) and not the  **Good!**  (with html style). Any method would do, whether through **javascript** or **jquery** as long as it plays the same role.

Example:

```
$value = "`<b> Good </b>`";

<div id = "true"><?php $value; ?></div>
```

And the div would simply have an output like this: `<b> Good </b>`

How could I do that? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Depending on your programming language of choice you can use regular expressions to stip out the html tags or use a ready made function. For php  for example I know its http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This PHP functoin `htmlspecialchars()`
example:

```
$value = "`<b> Good </b>`";

<div id = "true"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value); ?></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to except the element `<a>` from being disabled? Cause I want my link to stay as it is. And not being printed as `<a href = "#"> this Link </a>`

Comment: try this it will help you: <?php
$string = '<b>abc</b> <a href="www.google.com">google</a>';
$string=htmlspecialchars($string);

$patterns = array("/&lt;a/","/&lt;\/a&gt;/","/&quot;&gt;/");
$replacements = array('<a','</a>','</a>');

$expected_result = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);

echo $expected_result;
?>

Comment: I'ts almost the answer but there are some extra characters. From `www.google.com`, this was the output: `"www.google.com</a` Any idea?

Comment: Hope This will work: <?php
$string = '<b>abc</b> <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>';
$string=htmlspecialchars($string);
$patterns = array("/&lt;\/a&gt;/","/&gt;/","/&lt;a/","/&quot;/");
$replacements = array('</a>',' >','<a ','');
$expected_result = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
echo $expected_result;
?>

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simple solution to this:

&lt = less than
&rt = greater than

```
&lttag&gt Hello i am simple text not an HTML element &lt/tag&gt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery text() method like this: $("content").text()

Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the html-tags to html-tags.
E.g. 
`&lt;b&gt;Good!&lt;/b&gt;`

How this is done depends on the programming language your are using.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to add it to a Dom element then return the text.

Something like this.

Var div = document.createElement('div');

Div.innerhtml = ' **good**';

Var res = div.innerText;

In this case res would be equal to 'good'.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the jQuery text() method.

```
$('yourdiv').text(<b> Good! </b>);
```

Know more from [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

Tried utilizing `textarea` element ?

```js
$("textarea").html("<b> Good! </b>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting, is to whitelist some html tags in the input. See for example [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1376825/22146) for how to do it in php.